# Select the top N rows from each group

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Select the top N rows from each group, should return first row of the group.

[sample rows[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kql0.png)

From the above attached image, display 1, 3 and 4 rows. How to get this, can you help

Comment: Read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is getting ignored because it doesn't include enough detail. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Replace `MyTable` with your table name. This query will return top 2. As you did not mention in which order you want to return Top N records, I used `GROUP_Row_ID` to order. You can change it as per your need.

```
DECLARE @n INT = 2;
SELECT *
FROM   (   SELECT * ,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY AlternativeId
                                      ORDER BY GROUP_Row_ID ) AS rn
           FROM   MyTable ) t
WHERE  t.rn <= @n;
```